# Using numpy vector elements in Fraction module in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fractions

I'm trying to use elements from a numpy array as an input for the `Fraction` module and I'm getting the following error: *"TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances"*

For example, if I do:

```
Y  =  np.array([7,1], dtype='int64')  
X  =  Y[0]*3+Y[1]
```

And then:

```
a = Fraction(58,X)
```

I'll get the same error. I also tried to do  `X=X.astype('int')`, or `X=X.astype('int32')`, without success.

What do I have to do to convert the numpy array in a "Rational instance" that is needed for Fraction module?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Works fine for me

Comment: @MrE: works for me too, but I've seen similar failures with 32-bit NumPy/Python.

Comment: I use idle 64-bit Numpy/Python running in windows by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be one of the unfortunate artifacts of the way Numpy integers interact with Python's abstract classes (and it's also dependent on whether you run a 32-bit or 64-bit Python, because `dtype='int'` means either `np.int32` or `np.int64`, but never Python `int`).

Explicitly converting to Python `int` should work:

```
Fraction(58, int(X))
```

Comment: Is it worthy to use numpy integers then? Or should I simply define my vector as **Y=[7,1]** ?

Comment: @gabriel_papaiz: depends on whether you want to use NumPy functionality (e.g. vector operations) with your integers.